# Select data from a database

Tags: php

I am currently working on a signup/login system. The part where you can sign up is completely working and finished. The login part is almost  finished, I have one problem left:

I am making a code that checks if the password typed in the `<input>` is equal to the password is the SQL database. This is what I tried:

```
if($password == "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")
```

This doesn't work because the program compares the password to "SELECT....." and not to the password in the database itself.

Does someone know how I can make the program so that it compares to the password in the database and not to the text: "SELECT password..."?

Thanks

Comment: What you're asking is essentially how to use a database in PHP.  There are *many* tutorials and examples to get you started.  Try a Google search for something like "PHP MySQL tutorial".  You can walk through several tutorials fairly quickly to get a sense for how the tools work.  Any one of them is very likely to cover querying a database.

Comment: Also note, as you get started, that the code you're currently attempting implies two things: (1) SQL injection vulnerabilities are in your future; (2) You are planning to store user passwords in plain text.  Both of these are *very bad things*.  As you learn, it's worth your effort to include in your studies what SQL injection is and how to prevent it, as well as how to properly hash user passwords in PHP.

Comment: MySQL injection is putting code in the <input> right?

Comment: That's an oversimplification of it.  SQL injection is essentially executing any user-modifiable value as code.  Whether that value came from direct input, or from a database value, or from somewhere else is immaterial.  Note also that SQL injection does not always necessarily involve a malicious user.  Accidental damage and frequent bugs also result from SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

you are only using string, you need to send that string to mysql query, and return row;

this is a bit more complex, made to work with encrypted passwords

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="'.$link->real_escape_string($_POST['email']).'"';
$set = $link->query($sql); $num = $set->num_rows; list($id,$email,$pwd,$token ) = $set->fetch_row();

if ($num == 0) {
    echo json_encode([0,'ERROR: This user doesn&apos;t exist']); die(); 
} else if  ( $pwd != '#'.md5($_POST['password'].$token) ) {
    echo json_encode([0,'ERROR: Wrong password']); die();
} else {
    setcookie("UserID", $id, time()+3600,'/');  /* expire in 1 hour */
    setcookie("token", $token, time()+3600,'/');
    echo json_encode([1,'SUCCESS: Logged in successfully']); die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this specific question, you should be using something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name') && isset($_POST['user_pass'])){
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
```

and for the PHP you'll want to be using `form method="POST"`

and `<p>User Name</p><input type="text" name="user_name" />` etc

Answer (score 0):

Your queries is wrong my dear.
Again You did not show your code but am using Am using **PDO(PHP Portal Data Objects)**.

Adjust the **database name, username and password** in the code below to suit your own. Below is how you will do it. let me know if there is anything more i can do for you...

**Updated php code**

```
<?php

    $db = new PDO (
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Testing_db;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username

    '' // password
);

// assuming the username and password is coming from a form input

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


if ($username == ''){
echo "username is empty";
exit();
}


if ($password == ''){
echo "Password is empty";
exit();
}



$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username and password = :password');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

$count = $result->rowCount();
$row = $result->fetch();

if( $count == 1 ) {
echo "login sucessful";
// Redirect me to a Dasboard.php to display the login user
//echo "<script>window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";


$username = htmlspecialchars($row['username']);
echo "userame: $username </br>";



}
else {

echo "<font color=red>Either Username or Password is Wrong</font>";
}


?>
```

**Updated code.**

Create database as follows and insert into it. try it with inserted user account. name the php file eg **login.php**. please use the my php code above

Try it and it will work

```
create table users (id int primary key auto_increment, username varchar(30), password varchar(30));
insert into users(username,password)values('test','test123');
```

**here is your form**

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It says password is empty when is open my site

Comment: Or should this be in the action?

Comment: can you post  your form inputs. I need to see your password fields

Comment: again are u making an ajax call

Comment: <input type="apssword" name="password" etc>

Comment: See  the updated section of my answer on what to do. its working now...

Comment: It says: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\connect.inc.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\connect.inc.php on lin

Comment: copy my php code and run it now. it will work. I have tested it and fix the error then re upload it. Copy it again . pls let me know how it goes

Comment: It says it doent recognise prepare()